# Getting IPv6/64 ranges

Tags: ipv6

I use https://www.vultr.com/tools/subnet-calculator-ipv6/ to get the "Address Range Start" and "Address Range End" of my Linode VPS, I then added the IPs in /etc/network/interfaces and everything did work as expected.

However I have two different Linode instances now and even though I get different IPv6/64 IPs, when I use the subnet ipv6 calculator, I get identical start range and end range. Why is this happening? How can I get a list of IPv6 ips that I can use?

The two IPs are

```
2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fee5:1c9a / 64 
2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe60:42fb / 64
```

Comment: In most circumstances, your IPv6 address range will be a `/64`. Every address in the 64-bit prefix is usable as an address, from the all-zeroes to the all-ones in the last 64 bits. If your two addresses share the same 64-bit prefix, then you will end up with the same address range. You don't specify what the addresses are, so I can't tell if anything is wrong.

Comment: @RonMaupin I updated my question with the two IPs

Answer (score 2):

Your IP addresses are constructed from a single /64 link-prefix and the MAC addresses of each VM. The /64 looks like it is shared between all Linode customers in the data center.

That construction will only give you a single IP address per VM. It is likely that Linode have filters in place preventing you from using any other address in that /64 in order to prevent spoofing the IP address of another customer.

If you need more addresses the best solution from a technical point of view is that you get a shorter prefix (somewhere in the range from a /48 to a /60) routed to your VM.

I didn't find much detail on the [Linode](https://www.linode.com/linodes) website, but I did find this:

> Each Linode starts off with one global IPv6 address and additional IPv6 addresses can be added at no charge.

Answer (score 1):

Those two addresses are in the same `/64` prefix, so the valid address range will be exactly the same: `2600:3c03::` to `2600:3c03::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

The first 64 bits of the address is the network. In this case, it is `2600:3c03::`. The valid address range is all zeroes in the last 64 bits to all ones in the last 64 bits.*

That gives you a possible `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` addresses in that network that you can use.

---

*While IPv6, unlike IPv4, can use every address in a network for a host address, including the network address, and there is no broadcast in IPv6, so there is no broadcast address, the all-zeroes address is reserved for the router anycast address, and the last 127 addresses are reserved for anycast addresses (see [*RFC 2526, Reserved IPv6 Subnet Anycast Addresses*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2526.txt)). An anycast address is a unicast address that is shared among several hosts, so all the addresses in an IPv6 network are valid host addresses.